# Azure pipeline YAML: assign variable to another variable

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I want to define variable version_ that consists of other my variables, like this:
[image]

but variables major, minor, versionCounter and branchPrefix aren't recognized, and this syntax is just transformed into string

I tried to use $(major) syntax, but it also didn't work.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Hey, welcome on SO. Can you next time paste code instead of the screen. It helps a lot on providing an answer.

Comment: for some reason stackoverflow adds auxiliary characters when code is pasted, making it less readable, if it's fixed, i'll past code in future

Answer (score 0):

To set a pipeline variable you can use the [`echo ##vso`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts) syntax:

```
  - bash: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=initialBuild]$(Build.BuildNumber)"
    displayName: Save initial build number
```

or PowerShell

```
  - pwsh: |
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=initialBuild]$(Build.BuildNumber)"
    displayName: Save initial build number
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change `${{ }}` syntax on branchPrefix and version_ to `$[]`, however on condition with if you should have `${{ }}`.